# How to add a column with constant observation and another variable with consecutive numbers with a character in R

Tags: r, variables, dataframe

I want to add a first column with consecutive numbers with characters in a existing data frame.

I use the following code. It does not work.

```
df$VARNAME_ <- paste0('COL', 1:5)(df)
```

I want to it look like this.

```
VARNAME_ old_var1 old_var2
   COL1         1        2
   COL2         1        2
   COL3         1        2
   COL4         1        2
   COL5         1        2
```

Thanks in advance.

---

I am Sorry that I asked a stupid question. And now I figure out.
The solution is as following.

```
actual_df<-data.frame(df)#transfer matrix a to data frame
actual_df<-cbind(VARNAME_=paste0('COL', 1:5),actual_df) #add COL1~COL5 in the first column
actual_df<-cbind(ROWTYPE_ = 'PROX', actual_df) #Add a variable with constant observations in first column. Now the previous column become second one.
```

Comment: `df$VARNAME_ <- paste0('COL', 1:5)` by itself should work?

Comment: It shows "In a$VARNAME_ <- paste0("COL", 1:5) : Coercing LHS to a list"

Comment: I don't have any problem with that. Not sure.

Comment: Oh!! It works!! Thank you. I need to transfer my matrix to data frame first. Then, I use what you mentioned with 'cbind' to move VARNAME_ to the first column. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df$VARNAME_ = paste0('COL', 1:5)
```

will work